# Limitar EditText a 5 palabras separadas con coma - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buen día, quiero restringir un `EditText` para que solo acepte 5 palabras separadas por comas, por ejemplo: `alguien,bueno,cocinar,dinero,estirar`

¿Alguna sugerencia para poder realizar esto en Android?

Intente con este método pero no puedo escribir nada

```
Protected void validate_text(EditText text) {

        InputFilter[] filter = new InputFilter[1];
        filter[0] = new InputFilter() {

            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                       Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

                if (end > start) {
                    String destText = dest.toString();
                    String resultingText = destText.substring(0, dstart)
                            + source.subSequence(start, end)
                            + destText.substring(dend);
                    if (!resultingText
                            .matches("\\w,\\w,\\w,\\w,\\w")) {
                        return "";
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }
        };
        text.setFilters(filter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la verdad es que no estabas muy alejado en sobre cómo hacerlo pero te lo voy a hacer de forma que sea un poco más simplificada. Primero, vamos a crear un método para validar la cantidad de palabras:

```
public void contarPalabras() {
    //Lo primero es crear el string de lo que se ingresa en el EditText, 
    //como desconocemos si el usuario ingresará los espacios, le asignamos el trim()
    String palabra = palabras.getText().toString().trim();
    
    //Lo siguiente es crear un array String temporal para que cuenta las palabras
    //cada vez que se ingrese una coma
    String temp[] = palabra.split(",");

    //crearemos una variable de tipo int y le asignaremos el tamaño del array creado
    int cantidadPalabras = temp.length;

    Log.d("CANTIDAD", "contarPalabras: " + cantidadPalabras);
    //Adjunto una captura de cómo se ve cuando el contador es >5:
}
```

Contador > 5:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, tú quieres que el límite sea de 5, entonces haremos un `if` que resuelva la situación:

```
    if(cantidadPalabras == 5){
        palabras.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(cantidadPalabras)});
        Toast.makeText(this, "Límite alcanzado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Y se ve así: Contador == 5:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, solo debes añadir el método al `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    palabras = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.prueba);
    contarPalabras();
}
```